# Injecting Spring Boot component with Mockito mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Here is my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting) for reproducing the exact issue.

Not sure if this is a Spring Boot question or a Mockito question.

I have the following Spring Boot `@Component` class:

```
@Component
class StartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, KernelConstants {
    @Autowired
    private Fizz fizz;

    @Autowired
    private Buzz buzz;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // Do stuff involving 'fizz' and 'buzz'
    }
}
```

So `StartupListener` has no constructor and is intentionally a Spring `@Component` that gets its properties injected via `@Autowired`.

The `@Configuration` class providing these dependencies is here, for good measure:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Fizz fizz() {
        return new Fizz("OF COURSE");
    }

    @Bean
    public Buzz buzz() {
        return new Buzz(1, true, Foo.Bar);
    }
}
```

I am now trying to write a JUnit unit test for `StartupListener`, and I have been using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) with great success. I would like to create a **mock** `Fizz` and `Buzz` instance and inject `StartupListener` with them, but I'm not sure how:

```
public class StartupListenerTest {
  private StartupListener startupListener;

  @Mock
  private Fizz fizz;

  @Mock
  price Buzz buzz;

  @Test
  public void on_startup_should_do_something() {
    Mockito.when(fizz.calculateSomething()).thenReturn(43);

    // Doesn't matter what I'm testing here, the point is I'd like 'fizz' and 'buzz' to be mockable mocks
    // WITHOUT having to add setter methods to StartupListener and calling them from inside test code!
  }
}
```

**Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?**

---

#### Update

Please see my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting) for reproducing this exact issue.

Comment: use `@MockBean`

Comment: Are you getting any error? What exactly doesn't work for you? Just, probably, you are missing `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` or `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`.

Comment: Thanks @SergeiSirik (+1) but when I try that I get a NPE thrown from inside my configuration class (see my updates above which include full source code). Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Also @SergeiSirik please see my updates regarding the GitHub repo I pushed my code to; it reproduces the issue I'm seeing exactly! Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `@SpyBean`instead of `@MockBean`, `SpyBean` wraps the real bean but allows you to verify method invocation and mock individual methods without affecting any other method of the real bean.

```
  @SpyBean
  private Fizz fizz;

  @SpyBean
  price Buzz buzz;
```

Comment: Thanks @stacker (+1) do you have a reason to believe `@SpyBean` would work better than `@MockBean` in my given case? I'm willing to try it but not sure why one would work when the other doesn't...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@MockBean` to mock beans in `ApplicationContext`

> We can use the @MockBean to add mock objects to the Spring application context. The mock will replace any existing bean of the same type in the application context.
>
> If no bean of the same type is defined, a new one will be added. This annotation is useful in integration tests where a particular bean – for example, an external service – needs to be mocked.

**To use this annotation, we have to use SpringRunner to run the test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MockBeanAnnotationIntegrationTest {
 
@MockBean
private Fizz fizz;
 }
```

And i will also suggest to use `@SpringBootTest`

> The @SpringBootTest annotation tells Spring Boot to go and look for a main configuration class (one with @SpringBootApplication for instance), and use that to start a Spring application context.

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool (+1) but when I try that I get a NPE thrown from inside my configuration class (see my updates above which include full source code). Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: remove this method `setup` and also mock these `ContextRefreshedEvent` , `Init` with `@MockBean`

Comment: Thanks again (+1) please see my edits above which reflect your suggested changes. The same exact error persists, NPE thrown from the `authInfo()` bean creation method in the configuration class...

Comment: remove this `@Component` on `MyAppConfig` and add `@Autowired` on `private StartupListener startupListener;` in `StartupListenerTest` class and also change `SpringRunner` to `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`

Comment: Thanks again @Deadpool (+1) but still no change (see my edits above). Exact same error from the exact same location.

Comment: Just a thought, since `MyAppConfig` is populated by the fields I set in `application.json`, is there a `test-application.json` I should be using somewhere so that the `MyAppConfig` instance is non-null under the test scope?

Comment: Also @Deadpool please see my updates regarding the GitHub repo I pushed my code to; it reproduces the issue I'm seeing exactly! Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: from where this `TroubleshootingConfig` class properties will get injected? where is the application.yml? @hotmeatballsoup

Comment: Hi @Deadpool, its here: https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/blob/master/application.yml

Comment: move that to `src/main/resources/` @hotmeatballsoup, wait i will do it

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool but I need it externalized! Its an external config file, not to mention that I'm mocking the config [here](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/blob/master/src/test/java/troubleshooting/StartupListenerTest.java#L21) so the unit tests just need mock it all and shouldnt be reading the actual file!

Comment: the values from application.yml are not injecting into `TroubleshootingConfig` please that check that @hotmeatballsoup

Comment: and also application context is failing for this error `14:57:48.928 main [ERROR] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed`

Comment: Inside `StartupListenerTest`, the values from `application.yml` **should not** be injected, they should all be mocked. I'm not sure how/where you're getting that `SQLNonTransientConnectionException` but I'm not seeing that locally so its probably a difference between our MySQL installations. Either way, it wouldn't affect why this particular unit test is failing at the line its failing at!

Answer (score 3):

*you can do something likewise,*

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StartupListenerTest {

  @Mock
  private Fizz fizz;

  @Mock
  price Buzz buzz;

  @InjectMocks
  private StartupListener startupListener;

  @Test
  public void on_startup_should_do_something() {
Mockito.when(fizz.calculateSomething()).thenReturn(43);
....
  }
}
```

Comment: For **unit** tests this seems to me the best answer using field injection. Also, the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` is optional, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that just uses plain Spring.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q54318731;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Answer {

    /** The Constant SPRING_CLASS_RULE. */
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    /** The spring method rule. */
    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    static final AtomicInteger FIZZ_RESULT_HOLDER = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static final int FIZZ_RESULT = 43;

    static final AtomicInteger BUZZ_RESULT_HOLDER = new AtomicInteger(0);;
    static final int BUZZ_RESULT = 42;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        this.configurableApplicationContext
            .publishEvent(new ContextRefreshedEvent(this.configurableApplicationContext));

        // wait for it
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
        assertEquals(FIZZ_RESULT, FIZZ_RESULT_HOLDER.get());
        assertEquals(BUZZ_RESULT, BUZZ_RESULT_HOLDER.get());
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan //so we can pick up the StartupListener 
    static class Config {

        final Fizz fizz = Mockito.mock(Fizz.class);

        final Buzz buzz = Mockito.mock(Buzz.class);

        @Bean
        Fizz fizz() {

            Mockito.when(this.fizz.calculateSomething())
                .thenReturn(FIZZ_RESULT);
            return this.fizz;
        }

        @Bean
        Buzz buzz() {

            Mockito.when(this.buzz.calculateSomethingElse())
                .thenReturn(BUZZ_RESULT);
            return this.buzz;
        }
    }

    @Component
    static class StartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

        @Autowired
        private Fizz fizz;

        @Autowired
        private Buzz buzz;

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
            FIZZ_RESULT_HOLDER.set(this.fizz.calculateSomething());
            BUZZ_RESULT_HOLDER.set(this.buzz.calculateSomethingElse());
        }
    }

    static class Fizz {
        int calculateSomething() {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    static class Buzz {
        int calculateSomethingElse() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your StartupListenerTest to just focus on the StartupListener class

i.e. add the class to the SpringBootTest annotation

```
@SpringBootTest(classes= {StartupListener.class})
```

You will get a different error, but it's more focused on the class you're trying to test.

`onApplicationEvent` method will fire before the test runs. This means you won't have initialized your mock with `when(troubleshootingConfig.getMachine()).thenReturn(machine);` and so there's no Machine returned when getMachine() is called, hence the NPE.

The best approach to fix this really depends on what you're trying to achieve from the test. I would use an application-test.properties file to set up the TroubleShootingConfig rather than use an @MockBean. If all you're doing in your `onApplicationEvent` is logging then you could use @SpyBean as suggested in another answer to this question. Here's how you could do it.

Add an `application-test.properties` to resources folder so it's on the classpath:

```
troubleshooting.maxChildRestarts=4
troubleshooting.machine.id=machine-id
troubleshooting.machine.key=machine-key
```

Add `@Configuration` to `TroubleshootingConfig`

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "troubleshooting")
public class TroubleshootingConfig {
    private Machine machine;
    private Integer maxChildRestarts;
    ... rest of the class
```

Change `StartupListenerTest` to focus on the classes your testing and spy on the `TroubleshootingConfig`. You also need to `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= {TroubleshootingConfig.class, StartupListener.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class StartupListenerTest   {
    @Autowired
    private StartupListener startupListener;

    @SpyBean
    private TroubleshootingConfig troubleshootingConfig;

    @MockBean
    private Fizzbuzz fizzbuzz;

    @Mock
    private TroubleshootingConfig.Machine machine;

    @Mock
    private ContextRefreshedEvent event;

    @Test
    public void should_do_something() {
        when(troubleshootingConfig.getMachine()).thenReturn(machine);
        when(fizzbuzz.getFoobarId()).thenReturn(2L);
        when(machine.getKey()).thenReturn("FLIM FLAM!");

        // when
        startupListener.onApplicationEvent(event);

        // then
        verify(machine).getKey();
    }
}
```